# How to filter commits by author in SourceTree?

Tags: git

In the branch view of [SourceTree](http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/), I see all the commits. I'd like to filter the commits to show only the ones committed by me/someone. How can I do this? Thanks.

Comment: I wanted to upvote the question and the accepted answer, but unfortunately they are both 69.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

In Windows version (1.7):

1. Go to Search View (menu View > Search View, or press `Ctrl+3`)
2. Change the search filter using the dropdown on the right to 'Authors'
3. Type your query in the search bar

Comment: Alternatively you can simply click on the the 'Search' tab in the lower part of the main window. (in SourceTree 1.8.3.0)

Comment: Sorry I can't accept the answer. I can't validate it's working. I have work on a Linux laptop and source tree doesn't support Linux :(

Comment: +1. Tested in SourceTree 3.0.8 and this solution works.

Comment: I validated it & this solution works @AlikElzin-kilaka. You can accepts this answer.

Comment: in new version it is user not 'author'

Comment: What if I need to get all the commits by _two_ authors (e.g. Smith and Watson), how can I do that?

Answer (score 18):

On the MacOS version right now, but should be similar for Windows UI.

1. On the top left, there's a magnifying glass. Click that for the filter view.
2. In the search bar, enter the name of the author you want
3. There's a search dropdown to the right of the search input - change this to 'User'

Comment: Couldn't find the magnifying glass; ⌘3 got me to the search view